# IOS self.view.frame.width equals 0

Tags: ios

I am making a custom keyboard. In order to determine the orientation of some buttons I need to find the width of the keyboard. I do this by using:

```
self.view.frame.width
```

in my `viewDidLoad()` method.

However, it returns 0.

Comment: you can subscribe to `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` notification in `viewWillAppear` and check the height and width of keyboard in the notification selectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this can happen in two scenarios
1- you didn't set the size of the self.view (somehow ... if you created that view programmatically..)

2- if you didn't initialize that view at all ...

However if the keyboard width equals the viewcontroller width , you can use this code below:

```
CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
```

Comment: What would that look line in swift?

Comment: let width: CGFloat = UIScreen .mainScreen.bounds.size.width
something like that , i can't compile it now but you can figure it out with basic swift knowledge :D